# Android Studio | How to use On Click to switch between a fragment and activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

I am trying to use a button to switch between the fragment I am working on to a new activity. I am using the On Click listener to try switch. As well as using start activity. I think I may have to use fragment manager but I am unsure of how to use this.

This is the code I have.

```
addPlayers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(TeamManagementFragment.this,AddPlayer.class));
    }
});
```

The error message I have is "Cannot resolve constructor"

Your help would be greatly appreciated :).
Many thanks,
Edward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `AddPlayer` is your other activity you want to start, use the context from the `View v` argument as your first argument to the `new Intent` creation instead of using the current TeamManagementFragment instance since they are not a valid context.

```
addPlayers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), AddPlayer.class));
    }
});
```

See the docs page for Context to see which classes inherit from it : 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

Comment: Petey Thank you very much! This worked for me! Just out of interest, I assume the v.getContext() means it gets the view that it is on?

Comment: Yea! the `v` argument will actually be what view was clicked, this is because you can apply the same OnClickListener to many views. In the above example `v` will be equal to `addPlayers`.

Comment: I have done! I am trying to switch back between the new Add Player Activity and Team Management fragment. 

     startActivity(Intent(v.getContext(),TeamManagementFragment.class));

My error says it can't resolve method.

Comment: Just return the activity that you were on before,  you may want to look at this answer from another question : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10407371/794088

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that `AddPlayer` is an Activity.
So you can use `getActivity()` instead of `TeamManagementFragment.this`

Answer (score 0):

well I guess you didn't get the concept of activities and fragments. a fragment is basically a view which is hosted by an activity, and it's alive as long as the container activity lives. you can not use an intent to switch between these two.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as you are currently in fragment:

```
addPlayers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override public void onClick(View v) { 
    getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),AddPlayer.class)); 
    } 
});
```